# Unwanted backslash being generated when MySQL text field row is updated

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, post

I have code that is updating a MySQL table row through a textarea (all code on the same page). The update form (HTML part) is echo'ed out within a PHP if statement. When the user click's the 'edit' button, a textrea pops up (by use of Javascript). They type their update in and hit submit and it updates it in the MySQL database as well as on the site immediately. Here's the code:

---

**PHP (echo'ed HTML form)**

```
echo "<span id=\"about_me\">".$row['aboutme']."</span><span style=\"font-size:10px;\"><a id=\"popup\">Edit</a></span></p>
    <form style\"display:none;\" method=\"post\">
    <textarea rows=\"5\" cols=\"31\" id=\"area\" name=\"about_update\" style=\"display:none\" placeholder=\"Type 140 characters or less and press submit.\"></textarea>
    <input style=\"display:none;\" type=\"submit\" id=\"aboutsubmit\" value=\"Submit\" />
    </form>";
```

---

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['about_update'])) {
    $about_update = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['about_update']);
    $update = "UPDATE tbl_name SET aboutme='$about_update' 
        WHERE firstname='$firstname' && lastname='$lastname'";
    $mysqli->query($update);
}
```

It all functions correctly except when you use an apostrophe it places a `\` before it. The type of the `aboutme` row in MySQL is TEXT btw.  Why does the textarea generate this `\` ?

Comment: That has to do with escaping. At least, I cannot think of another reason.

Comment: Yeah I figured that too, I'm assuming the PHP is interpreting it that way, I just don't know how to prevent it...

Comment: stripslashes() or stripcslashes() would probably do the trick. Read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: Make sure you have disabled `magic_quotes_gpc` also.  This can be done in your .htaccess file like `php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off`

Comment: You also should real_escape $firstname and $lastname, even if they don't come from the user directly.

Comment: yes it is good practice to escape always. I use a class. $db->s($a_string) and $db->i($an_integer) etc always.

Comment: @Digitalis, your solution worked! Feel free to add it so I can accept it. mmmshuddup, I will look into yours. And Adder, I escaped $firstname and $lastname earlier in the code. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Thanks, I had to be elsewhere last night. However, you have an answer already I see. The main point is that someone provided a correct answer that makes you understand *why* this went wrong. Therefore I suggest that, if you do, you just pay the man!

Comment: Another suggestion, just something to think about, I would consider switching to PDO as it supports more than just mysql and is a lot more secure and robust. I'm really recommending http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-Data-Object/PDO-Tutorial-P842.html to get the drop on pdo.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't got access to your php.ini file, the following function should work:

```
function escapeString($value){
global $mysqli;
  if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
    $value=stripslashes($value);
  }
  $value=$mysqli->real_escape_string($value);
  return $value;
}
```

Make sure you put the function after opening the db connection :)

Instead of your

```
$mysqli->real_escape_string();
```

Put

```
$someVariable=escapeString($variableYouWantToEscspe);
```

Hope this works!

Edit: What is happening is the apostrophe is being escaped once by the magic quote then the escaped string is being escaped again by the real_escape_string function. What you want to do is remove any backslashes only if magic quotes has inserted them (first if statement) then escape the string, or if magic quotes isn't on, just escape the string :)

Comment: I think escapeString needs SQLite3 switching on. Won't stripslashes do?

Comment: escapeString is a self defined function? It doesn't need anything else other than an open db connection.stripslashes is only needed if magic quotes are turned on, otherwise just escape it.

Comment: Yup :) you could rename the function if you wanted to :) see my edit for the explanation on how it works

Comment: Sorry, I made some mistakes in the code, should work fine now!

Comment: sorry I didn't even notice you wrote the function up there I just recognised its name. I should get some sleep